# Forgot mysql owner/root username and password

Tags: mysql, password

Recently, I changed my mysql `root` user to someother username (say `kevin`). But, now both the accounts don't login with the old password. It says `access denied`.

I'm also not sure if the username is that (`kevin`). How can I retrieve both the root username and password?

I also tried resetting my mysql root password but I cannot, it says `Access denied`. Even if I use the root username, it logs in but I cannot see any database like `mysql` (Clearly, I don't have any privilege). Just the two basic databases are accessible. I am using Ubuntu 13.10, if that helps.

PS - I cannot reinstall mysql as I have important data stored in the databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a variety of options to reset the password http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/recovering-a-mysql-root-password-the-fourth-solution

UPD:
Following the Max's advice let me elaborate. The easiest way to reset any password is to restart MySQL with `skip-grant-tables` in `my.cnf`. Then MySQL won't ask the password. To set new password execute this:

```
 mysql -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET password = PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user = 'root' and host = '<host>'"
```

where <host> is host where user connects form.

Then restart MySQL again, but without `skip-grant-tables` option.

Comment: In order to avoid link-rot, you might want to add some of the salient points from that page into your answer...